# iMac keyboard alternative

Tags: mac, keyboard, wireless-networking, software-rec, ergonomics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which keyboard would you recommend?](https://superuser.com/questions/253/which-keyboard-would-you-recommend)

Not sure if this belongs on serverfault but here goes

I just got a Mac and find

- the mouse to be completely awesome, truly, the more I use it, the better it gets
- the keyboard to be an epic fail, a true exercise of style over substance, yes you can type on it, but you can on my phone (doesn't make it a pleasurable experience) loads of the keys are missing etc

I am a touch typist and I also appreciate having a numeric keypad and all the usual edit/arrow keys

Previously I was using a Microsoft Natural Keyboard which was pretty good but

- it's not wireless
- it's black
- it's MASSIVE (think Ford Sierra Cosworth whale tail with keys on it)

Does anyone have experience with a better keyboard?

Criteria to meet

- num/edit keys
- not too huge
- wireless
- white
- optional: USB ports, volume controls

Comment: It belongs here, but has basically been handled: http://superuser.com/questions/253/which-keyboard-would-you-recommend

Comment: It is not an exact duplicate. First line of other post "it does not need to be wireless". My criteria "wireless". ffs.

Answer (score 1):

Any USB keyboard will work on the macintosh....  Drivers are only needed if they have special keys (eg.  Play music, surf the internet, etc)  And even those are sometimes recognized by Mac OS X.

The keyboard control panel, allows you to remap keys to other functions as well, so if the key isn't recognized, you can remap it to do something else...

As for specific keyboards...  If it's a recent purchase, check the store you purchased it from the "FULL SIZE" macintosh keyboard is available with every model, you just happened to order it with the mini-keyboard.  They maybe willing to swap keyboards, at no charge...

I use the full size keyboard, and love it.